# Hide/Show Elements not Working on Mobile/Tablet, only Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 buttons, ***Check*** & ***Back***.

When a user clicks ***Check***, the button should change to ***Back*** so they cannot click ***Check*** 2 times in a row. However, on mobile view in chrome devtools, this does not work.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

```
<button type="button" class='btn goCheck' id="goCheck" data-show="back" style="width: 100%;">Check</button>

<button type="button" class='btn goBack' id="back" style="width: 100%; display: none;" onClick="refreshPage()">Back</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.goCompare').click(function(){
    $('.goCheck').hide() 
    $('.selectBtn').hide()
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-show')).show()
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you add the `refreshPage` function?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you're mixing `javascript` and `jquery`. So I just went with `jquery` fully to solve this making minimal changes to your original code. I rewrote the `refreshPage` function to fire on the click on the `back` button. I also removed the `onclick` method in the html. It seems to work for me in devTools as well. Hopefully this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.goCompare').click(function(){
    $('.goCompare').hide() 
    $('.selectBtn').hide()
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-show')).show()
  })
})

//Refresh Page script
  $(document).on('click', '#back',function(){
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class='btn goCompare' id="goCompare" data-show="back" style="width: 100%;">Compare</button>

<button type="button" class='btn goBack' id="back" style="width: 100%; display: none;">Back</button>
```

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't change from "Compare" to "Back" on mobile. Is there something else that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your devtools console? Because maybe there is something else in your code that's causing the issue.

Comment: How are you running devtools? Are you just loading the page and pressing f12? And which mobile view are you using?

Comment: On Chrome I just right click and inspect. Im using the iPhone X view.

Comment: What version of Chome do you have? I just copied the code into a blank notepad and saved it as a html and opened it with my chrome and used devtools, it seemed to work for me on every mobile view. I have version 78.0

Comment: I have version Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit). I also just copied the code and tested the same way you did and it works...but on my application it doesn't...

Comment: I think there is something else with your application that's causing the functionality to not work. I don't know what application you're using, but the core code that I posted works under normal circumstances.

Comment: I just tested it again and it seems that when I take this code from here and paste it onto my page, it works, but when my actual button element that I need to work doesnt work if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this answer in Chrome Devtools and confirmed functionality.

I think jquery is overkill here and I think it would be better if you only had one button that was controlled by an event listener.

```js
    document.getElementById("goCompareBack").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (document.getElementById("goCompareBack").innerHTML === "Back") {
            refreshPage();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("goCompareBack").innerHTML = "Back";
            compare();
        }
    })
    
    function refreshPage() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    
    function compare() {
        // comparing logic here
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class='btn goCompareBack' id="goCompareBack" data-show="compareBack" style="width: 100%;">Compare</button>
```

Comment: Same problem as the other person who attempted to help. I do like this approach of using one button though. Any ideas on what else I can check for issues?

Comment: My Chrome is "Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

What is yours?

Comment: Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Then it must be something else in the application causing it to fail.

Is there a demo or a working version of the site you have up?

Comment: No I don't unfortunately, but I just tested it again and it seems that when I take this code from here and paste it onto my page, it works, but when my actual button element that I need to work doesnt work if that makes sense.

Comment: Edit the question to include the button element and any JS with it please

Comment: I have tested and figured out that your code works in my files, up until I edit the "ElementID" to match what I have in the "other functions" code I have added to my question. Once I do that, it stops working again. Is something wrong with these functions?